# Overflow-x:hidden and Overflow-y:hidden won't work with window.ScrollTo();

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can get my website to look how I want it on my tablet but then scrollTo doesn't work which is used in the navbar. It's not looking right for my tablet. Right now, this is what my css looks like to have the results in the picture below. Also, this code looks and works fine for iPhone as well.

```
html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is the code to get it to look properly on my android tablet, but then scroll behavior with the navbar is lost.

```
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'm having a really hard time pinpointing the issue and finding a solution.

[What the first page looks like on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqRfI.jpg)

[What the second page should look like after pressing the >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdtr.jpg)

[What it looks like on my tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZjg.png)

[Image of what it looks like on my tablet zoomed out all the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpRk0.png)

Comment: Do you want to make a slideshow of pages ? By that I mean when we press the left and right arrows, we go to next page, and the problem is that you are shown all the pages when we zoom out .Can you please confirm my understanding of the problem.

Comment: Yes that is what is happening and what I would like to accomplish. The problem only occurs on my android device for some reason. Even though, I have set overflow-x and y to be hidden in the body.

Comment: you can  try hiding other pages when you don't want them to be shown and only make the appropriate one visible when the nav button is pressed( can be done using js)